# Spark Standalone NodeManager kills workers

Tags: apache-spark, executor

I'm facing the following problem in two of my spark job, the first one is an algorithm which treat 1M data and make a reduceByKey over 20000 partitions on an important number of keys.
The second is spark random forest on 300000 data over 10000partitions.
In both case i'm falling on this problem, spark kill and create hundreds of executors without moving forward...

```
INFO AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20170111091905-0328/16 is now RUNNING
INFO AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20170111091905-0328/15 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20170111091905-0328/15 removed: Command exited with code 1
INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 15 from BlockManagerMaster.
```

In the first case it happen to the reduceBykey step.
For the second case it happen at : reduce at randomForest.scala:94

My config is as follow : spark 1.6.2, 3 slaves with one worker each with 4cores 6Go MEM, 2Go MEM for driver

I try to find answear but all i found was to increase the akka.framesize what i've done without changes and increase the MEM on worker...
I also red that for the second case it can going from a too large number of trees in the forest.
Moreover i didn't find any clear explanations which justify thoses answears.

Thank you in advance

Comment: My guess is that you have too many partitions for the number of data, and the shuffle during reduceByKey operation is consuming more resource than is available. More information may be available in your worker logs.

Comment: I reduced the number of partitions to 200, it helped for the random forest but not for the first case with the reduceByKey..

Comment: The log you have posted indicates that an executor is having problems, but doesn't tell us what those are.  Please can you look at the executor logs to see if there is a stacktrace etc. for the actual error. reduceByKey is an expensive operation, without your executor logs my guess is that the shuffle operation is taking down an executor, or perhaps there is too much data for a particular key.